# Visualize full UCC circuit in qiskit

Tags: qiskit, programming, quantum-circuit

I am experimenting with the UCC module in qiskit nature. From `pyscf`, I got 1-body and 2-body integrals (I need to use custom integrals) and thus created a mapped Hamiltonian. Then, I create a UCC object and find the optimal parameters, and finally, I visualize the circuit. The code I used (without imports & `pyscf`-overhead) is shown below.

```
electronic_energy = ElectronicEnergy.from_raw_integrals(
    ElectronicBasis.MO, one_body_ints, two_body_ints
)
hamiltonian = electronic_energy.second_q_ops()[0]
qubit_converter = QubitConverter(mapper=JordanWignerMapper())
qubit_op = qubit_converter.convert(hamiltonian,num_particles=num_particles)
initial_state = HartreeFock(
        num_spin_orbitals=num_spin_orbitals,
        num_particles=num_particles,
        qubit_converter=qubit_converter,
    )
reps=1
var_form = UCC(
    excitations="sd",
    num_particles=num_particles,
    num_spin_orbitals=num_spin_orbitals,
    initial_state=initial_state,
    qubit_converter=qubit_converter,
    reps=reps,
)
optimizer=COBYLA(maxiter=1000)
vqe = VQE(ansatz=var_form, optimizer=optimizer,quantum_instance=Aer.get_backend("aer_simulator_statevector"))
vqe_result =vqe.compute_minimum_eigenvalue(qubit_op)
from qiskit.tools.visualization import circuit_drawer
circuit=vqe.get_optimal_circuit()
circuit_drawer(circuit, output='mpl', plot_barriers=False)
plt.show()
```

I thought that I could visualize the full circuit by printing/drawing the circuit object. This is however not the case, all I get is the following:

[image: Not well visualized UCC circuit]

How can I visualize the full circuit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`QuantumCircuit.decompose()`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.decompose.html) for shallow decomposition

```
circuit.decompose().draw('mpl')
```

The result will be
[image]

For further decomposition you can call `decompose()` multiple times:

```
circuit.decompose().decompose().draw('mpl')
```

or use `reps` parameter to specify the number of times the circuit should be decomposed:

```
circuit.decompose(reps = 6).draw('mpl')
```

Another option is to use [Unroller](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.transpiler.passes.Unroller.html) transpiler pass which allows you to specify the target basis gate set:

```
from qiskit.transpiler.passes import Unroller
from qiskit.converters import circuit_to_dag, dag_to_circuit

# You can specify the target basis gate set:
unroller = Unroller(basis=['u', 'cx'])
unrolled_circuit = dag_to_circuit(unroller.run(circuit_to_dag(circuit)))
unrolled_circuit.draw('mpl')
```